# AutoComplete textfield with static array data in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, autocomplete, uitextfield

I have a static array of cities names. I have a text-field and a table-view under it. When I type a city name it shows my array in table-view correctly, but it is not working when I type any letter.

#### For Example - If I enter K it should show city name starting with K in the table-view.

My code is,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return [city count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

  if (cell == nil) {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  cell.textLabel.text=[city objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

UITableViewCell *selectedCell=[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSLog(@"%@",selectedCell.textLabel.text);
    self.cityName.text=[city objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.autotable.hidden=YES;    
}
```

and here is a method for on Changed on text-field,

```
- (IBAction)editonChanged:(id)sender {
  if(self.cityName.text.length>3)
  {
    
    [self getAutoCompletePlaces:self.cityName.text];
  }
}

-(void)getAutoCompletePlaces:(NSString *)searchToken
{
  if(city.count >0)
  {
    self.autotable.hidden=NO;
    [_autotable reloadData];
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show some additional code getAutoCompletePlaces

Comment: its the full code that i have used for it. @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: what is this `If I enter K it should show city name starting with K ` ,but you called this line `if(self.cityName.text.length>3)` then how it comes on first char

Comment: @Oneeb you should filter array in getAutoCompletePlace before reload

Comment: How can i use them. @Abhishek

Comment: If any city in my array start with K alphabet when user try to enter city starting from K it should show that city first, rather than the array as it is. @Anbu.Karthik

Answer (score 0):

For Filtering you city with searched String you can try to use below code

```
-(void)getAutoCompletePlaces:(NSString *)searchToken
{
  //Store original city array at somewhere to reset filtering

  if(searchToken.length >0)
  {
    NSMutableString *arg = [NSMutableString string];
    [arg appendString:@"\\s*\\b"];
    [arg appendString:searchToken];
    [arg appendString:@"\\b\\s*"];
    //arg above is for exact matching string which comes to start, mid or end
    NSPredicate *matchPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF matches[c] %@", arg]; 
    //Format can be 'SELF CONTAINS[c]' than 'SELF MATCHES[c]' both work with different needs

    //For 'CONTAINS' format no need to create arg
    NSPredicate *containPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", arg]; 

    //Get new filtered array from old city array
    NSArray *newArray = [city filteredArrayUsingPredicate:containPredicate]; //can be matchPredicate

    //use newArray to reload table
    city = newArray

    //Reload
    self.autotable.hidden=NO;
    [_autotable reloadData];
  }
}
```

you can modify predicate format according to you

Comment: It is not showing with the alphabet , it is just showing an array as it is. @Abhishek

Comment: Write predicate format "SELF CONTAINS[c] %@", It would work

Comment: @Oneeb updated answer try with matchPredicate and containPradicate both, previously 'city = newArray' not written so may be not working

Comment: let me try. @Abhishek

Comment: It is showing nothing now in a table view. @Abhishek

Comment: It is showing nothing to me in table view. @Abhishek

Comment: If the table is empty this means newArray is Empty, but this is how filtering works. Check full code maybe something missing.

Comment: we have to pass new array to the table view datasources? @Abhishek

Comment: city = newArray This line already updating city with newArray

Comment: Than where is the problem coming. @Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest [filtering a UITableView with a search bar](http://code-ninja.org/blog/2012/01/08/ios-quick-tip-filtering-a-uitableview-with-a-search-bar/) instead of using a text field. By sounds of what your trying to achieve, take a look at the tutorial and adjust your code accordingly.

**Updated:** If you want to keep using your text field just filter the array after setting up a notification for the text field and then update it. I haven't tested this but give it a try.

```
[self.cityName addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

-(void)textFieldDidChange :(UITextField *)theTextField{
    if(self.cityName.text.length>0) {
        [self getAutoCompletePlaces:self.cityName.text];
    }
}

-(void)getAutoCompletePlaces:(NSString *)searchToken {
    if(city.count > 0) {
        city = [city filterUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@", searchToken]]; //Filters the array by the key word or character.
        self.autotable.hidden=NO;
        [_autotable reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: I want it in a textfield . @Benny Boy

Comment: Just updated it, not entirely sure if it will solve your problem as it will filter the 'city' array which means it will become unsorted. @Oneeb